# Reinstall Ubuntu 16.04 with UEFI, LUKS encryption and LVM

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, encryption, lvm

I had a disaster following an ubuntu update that went wrong

end result was my /boot dir got deleted

it also seems that my /proc dir also now contains nothing

when I boot the machine it just drops straight into the BIOS

Note, when I say BIOS I may mean UEFI, I'm pretty sure the machine has UEFI

The situation is complicated by the fact that I have LVM and LUKS full disk encryption on the machine.

My approach to fix this was to boot off a liveUSB and do a reinstall

However, when I get to the Installation type screen it tells me the machine has no operating systems.

I know it does as I've had the HDD out of the laptop to do an emergency backup using an external enclosure and another machine.

I'm thinking I need to choose 'Something else' at this point and then specify the appropriate device.

Doing this I reach the Installation type screen:

[image]

But I'm stuck at this point, aware that if I do the wrong thing it could cause me to have to go down the starting again from scratch route that I wish to avoid.

I think I should choose the sda1 (fat32) device as the boot loader installation point, but I'm not 100%

Possibly a reinstall is not the way to go and I can fix the boot dir some other way?

Update: It just crossed my mind that I should go in via the liveusb and unencrypt the laptops hdd and then run install as it may then recognise it and offer me the option of reinstall whilst keeping my home dir etc. etc.

Update2:

Have unencrypted the disk - tried boot-repair but it hasn't hepled

Now I've gone back into the installer..

In the Installation type, my options are now different due to the unencrypt:

[image]

I was a bit dissapointed that the installer was still telling me no OS was installed - so still had to click on 'Something else'

But this looks more like it, anyone know which device I should use for boot loader installation

Note to everyone out there - think carefully about using full disk encryption, whilst it may make it hard for others to get your data, it can also make it hard to get your own data! It certainly makes fixing your /boot dir and doing reinstalls more tricky..

Update3:

[image]

Took a pic of gparted for completeness. sda1 must be the uefi boot partition as its fat32. Not quite sure what the 244MB ext2 partition is. sda3 contains whats left of my ubuntu OS, and I can see it fine in nautilus. The whole root filesystem is there. I think boot-repair has done something as /boot is no longer empty - it looks like this:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ls -l /media/ubuntu/35270969-3a72-4de9-893c-5bf95758468e/boot/
total 46780
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1249685 Jan 19 13:06 abi-4.4.0-112-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   190533 Jan 19 13:06 config-4.4.0-112-generic
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     4096 Feb  2 16:47 efi
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10422531 Feb  2 16:48 initrd.img-4.4.0-104-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 17907657 Feb  2 16:48 initrd.img-4.4.0-112-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  3891234 Jan 19 13:06 System.map-4.4.0-112-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  7110608 Jan 19 13:06 vmlinuz-4.4.0-112-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  7112536 Feb  2 16:48 vmlinuz-4.4.0-112-generic.efi.signed
```

note this also shows how the LUKS encrypted drive has been mounted, i.e.

```
/media/ubuntu/35270969-3a72-4de9-893c-5bf95758468e
```

what seems to be missing here is a grub dir?

I also mounted sda1 and sda2 to have a look whats in them:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/test-sda1/
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount /dev/sda2 /media/test-sda2/

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ls -l /media/test-sda1/EFI/ubuntu/
total 3472
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 Jan  4  2017 fw
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   67536 Jan 31 09:19 fwupx64.efi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     121 Jan 15 19:00 grub.cfg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1133944 Jan 15 19:00 grubx64.efi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1168464 Jan 15 19:00 mmx64.efi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1169992 Jan 15 19:00 shimx64.efi

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ls -l /media/test-sda2
total 558
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root   1024 Jan 18  2016 efi
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root   1024 Jan 31 09:26 grub
drwx------ 2 root root  12288 Jan 18  2016 lost+found
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 182704 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 184380 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 184840 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
```

don't know if thats relevant?

Update 4:

Have now generated a boot-summary at http://paste.ubuntu.com/26509702/

Two advanced boot-repair options that caught my eye as potentially wrong:

1. secureBoot being selected
2. GRUB location separate boot partition sda2 unselected

[image]
[image]

```
cryptsetup: WARNING: invalid line in /etc/crypttab for luks-eab09f57-2c9d-4f3e-b81b-20061bb31685 - 
cryptsetup: WARNING: invalid line in /etc/crypttab for luks-eab09f57-2c9d-4f3e-b81b-20061bb31685 - 

An error occurred during the repair.

Please write on a paper the following URL:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/26513410/


In case you still experience boot problem, indicate this URL to:
boot.repair@gmail.com 

You can now reboot your computer.
Please do not forget to make your BIOS boot on sda1/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi file!
```

Comment: You may be able to use Boot-Repair and its advanced options to totally reinstall grub and new boot files. But as you surmise you need to make sure you have unencrypted your LVM partition first, so updates/installs will see it. lBe sure to boot in UEFI boot mode.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: the ubuntu installer seemed to think I have UEFI, its a 2015 laptop so it probably is. I'm pretty sure its got UEFI related bits in what I would call the 'BIOS' in old school language. I had to disable secure boot a while back after a virtual box update failed. I think that may be a UEFI thing?

Comment: Since you have the ESP - efi system partition as sda1, it just about has to be UEFI installs. And almost all systems since Windows 8 released 5 years ago are UEFI hardware, but can support the 35 year old BIOS/MBR configuration. If installing any proprietary drivers, you have to have UEFI secure boot off.

Comment: no joy running boot-repair after unencrypting sda3 - still broken. Back on the reinstall route, its still not recognising an existing OS though which is a real shame!

Comment: i don't have to unencrypt anyhting other than sda3 do I?

Comment: Boot-Repair should automount the ESP & /boot. But grub updates need to see / (root). So unencrypting and mounting LVM should let Boot-Repair restore booting. Post link to Summary Report to see if install looks otherwise normal. Do you have UEFI set to boot in UEFI boot mode? Secure boot off?

Comment: secure boot is off, i'm pretty sure its in UEFI boot mode, if I hold down F12 I get the UEFI boot order menu. see update3 for more info. It looks like boot-repair has gone some way to rebuilding /boot dir but theres still no grub dir. I asked for a summary report last time but didn't get one. I'll try running boot-repair again and see if I can get a link to one (I did get one the very 1st time i ran boot-repair)

Comment: is there any danger in running boot-repair more than once?

Comment: It does save data, so if very small file system, you may have to clean out logs.

Comment: im wondering whehter the efi and grub dirs in sda2 somehow have to be bound/linked to the /boot dir on sda3?

Comment: just been looking through some of the boot-repair advanced options - few question marks over some of the settings - will post another update..

Comment: Looks like standard full drive encryption with separate ESP - efi system partition and separate /boot partition. You must include both of those and unencrypt your / for Boot-Repair to reinstall files. Not sure you need Secure Boot but that is a different kernel for UEFI Secure Boot. But if you need proprietary drivers, you will not be able to use Secure Boot anyway. If new user best not to use LVM as that is an advanced volume management system, But LVM is required if you must have full drive encryption.

Comment: I think I give up - spent 3 days on this and still not working.. Time for a fresh reinstall and all the pain of reconfiguring my entire system

Comment: My takeaway from this is it your running LVM and LUKS your making a boot repair *way* harder than it would otherwise be. Plus copying large volumes of files > 100GB in Linux is badly broken. It's crazy this problem persists and so many people experience it!